# c# - LINQ find 2D jagged array minimum, return index

Tags: c#, linq

I have a standard 2D jagged array `int[][] arr`.

Let's call `i` and `j` the indices for row and column.

I'd like to retrieve via LINQ the indices `i` and `j` which points to the minimum of the matrix.

An idea of what I am trying to achieve is bri

```
from num in arr
where min = (from num in arr select min(num))
select i, j
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the the overloads of `SelectMany` and `Select` that include the index and then `OrderBy` and `First` to get one of the sets of indexes with the minimum value.

```
var min = arr.SelectMany((subArr, i) => subArr.Select((value, j) => new { i, j, value }))
    .OrderBy(x => x.value)
    .First();
int firstIndex = min.i;
int secondIndex = min.j;
```

Comment: Let me be sure I understood your snippet (there should be a LINQ master degree, sometimes can be very obscure!)
`SelectMany` divides the jagged array in columns `subArr` and their index. For each `subArr` it `Select`s the pair `value, j` where j is the index in current array, then we order by values. Why not using `Min` instead of `OrderBy`? it would break it all?

Comment: @Fylax `Min(x => x.value)` would only return the minimum `value` and not the anonymous class that contains the indexes.

Comment: That makes sense!

Comment: @Fylax You could also check out the [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq) library that contains a `MinBy` extension method that would work here instead of the `OrderBy` and `First`.

Comment: thank you a lot, I will take a look at it. Actually that's not my full problem but a simplified version to let me understand if think may work through LINQ or I need old-style nested loops

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this:

```
var result = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, arr.Length)
             from j in Enumerable.Range(0, arr[i].Length)
             orderby arr[i][j]
             select new { i, j };
var r = result.FirstOrDefault();// here is the indexes of min value
```